# Issues when inserting Data into MySQL Table from a C# App

Tags: c#, mysql

so i host a MySQL Database on PhpMyAdmin and the table looks like this:
[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZRoT.png)

Then i use this to insert Data into it:

```
using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = mysql.iniHandle())
{
    using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        if (!mysql.open(mySqlConnection))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Name`, `CPU`, `Skype`, `Se7ensins`, `PayPal`, `Tool`, `Menu`) VALUES (@Name, @CPU, @Skype, @Se7ensins, @PayPal, @Tool, @Menu)";
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPU", CPU);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skype", Skype);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Se7ensins", S7);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayPal", PayPal);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tool", Authed4Tool);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Menu", Authed4Menu);
            }
            catch(MySqlException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Id is a AI Primary Key, i thougth i just let the MySQL handle it(correct me if i'm wrong on this...)
Also just saying that mysql.iniHandle() returns a new MySQL Connection with the connection string, reading of using the "Select * From users" query works, so the missing connection is not the problem... Would be nice if anybody could help me on this :) i'm really stuck on this i did some research and also tried some code from the web but nothing seemed to help me...

Comment: Do you actually ever try executing the command, i.e. calling `mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: @TedSales Ohh lord jesus, that was embarrasing xD i looked for like everything, things like that always happen to me...

Comment: Haha don't worry, happens to everyone at some point! It's nice when the answer is simple, too.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery()   :)

Comment: @TedSales Yeap, it happens to everyone at some point ;)